# Count blocks of data based on id and status code

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

I have a dataset that looks something like this

| id | status | datetime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 0 | 07/02/2023 12:43 |
| 123456 | 4 | 07/02/2023 12:49 |
| 123456 | 5 | 07/02/2023 12:58 |
| 123456 | 5 | 07/02/2023 13:48 |
| 123456 | 7 | 07/02/2023 14:29 |
| 123456 | 0 | 07/02/2023 14:50 |
| 123456 | 4 | 07/02/2023 14:50 |
| 123456 | 5 | 07/02/2023 14:51 |
| 123456 | 9 | 07/02/2023 15:27 |
| 567890 | 0 | 07/02/2023 11:44 |
| 567890 | 4 | 07/02/2023 12:23 |
| 567890 | 5 | 07/02/2023 12:29 |
| 567890 | 5 | 07/02/2023 13:26 |
| 567890 | 5 | 07/02/2023 13:28 |
| 567890 | 5 | 07/02/2023 13:28 |
| 567890 | 5 | 07/02/2023 13:29 |
| 567890 | 9 | 07/02/2023 13:55 |

For each id in the dataset there are a number of statuses that need to be identified as 'blocks' of activity, where each block starts with a status code of 0 (and is sorted by datetime)

What I'd like to do is to add a column that identifies this block.  So my data would look like this with that column added.

| id | status | datetime | block |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 0 | 07/02/2023 12:43 | 1 |
| 123456 | 4 | 07/02/2023 12:49 | 1 |
| 123456 | 5 | 07/02/2023 12:58 | 1 |
| 123456 | 5 | 07/02/2023 13:48 | 1 |
| 123456 | 7 | 07/02/2023 14:29 | 1 |
| 123456 | 0 | 07/02/2023 14:50 | 2 |
| 123456 | 4 | 07/02/2023 14:50 | 2 |
| 123456 | 5 | 07/02/2023 14:51 | 2 |
| 123456 | 9 | 07/02/2023 15:27 | 2 |
| 567890 | 0 | 07/02/2023 11:44 | 1 |
| 567890 | 4 | 07/02/2023 12:23 | 1 |
| 567890 | 5 | 07/02/2023 12:29 | 1 |
| 567890 | 5 | 07/02/2023 13:26 | 1 |
| 567890 | 5 | 07/02/2023 13:28 | 1 |
| 567890 | 5 | 07/02/2023 13:28 | 1 |
| 567890 | 5 | 07/02/2023 13:29 | 1 |
| 567890 | 9 | 07/02/2023 13:55 | 1 |

I've used window functions before, but I can't get my head around how to do this.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Apologies - tried pasting data from Excel and the site wanted to paste as an image.  SQL Server data just looked messy once it was pasted in.

Comment: Use DDL and DML, or otherwise a markdown table. Images are *not* helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get the desired result using CTE and the below query

Sample Table:

```
CREATE TABLE SampleData (
  id INT,
  status INT,
  datetime DATETIME
);
```

Sample Data:

```
INSERT INTO SampleData (id, status, datetime)
VALUES
  (123456, 0, '07/02/2023 12:43'),
  (123456, 4, '07/02/2023 12:49'),
  (123456, 5, '07/02/2023 12:58'),
  (123456, 5, '07/02/2023 13:48'),
  (123456, 7, '07/02/2023 14:29'),
  (123456, 0, '07/02/2023 14:50'),
  (123456, 4, '07/02/2023 14:50'),
  (123456, 5, '07/02/2023 14:51'),
  (123456, 9, '07/02/2023 15:27'),
  (567890, 0, '07/02/2023 11:44'),
  (567890, 4, '07/02/2023 12:23'),
  (567890, 5, '07/02/2023 12:29'),
  (567890, 5, '07/02/2023 13:26'),
  (567890, 5, '07/02/2023 13:28'),
  (567890, 5, '07/02/2023 13:28'),
  (567890, 5, '07/02/2023 13:29'),
  (567890, 9, '07/02/2023 13:55');
```

Query:

```
  WITH CteSampleData AS (
  SELECT *,
         SUM(CASE WHEN status = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
         OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY datetime) AS block
  FROM SampleData
)
SELECT id, status, datetime, block
FROM CteSampleData
ORDER BY id, datetime;
```

Comment: You don't even need the CTE here. The windowed aggregate is the important part *not* the common table expression.